# Find k nearest integers for every element in array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers. I need to find k nearest integers for every element in array. (without element itself)

Example:

```
k = 2
Array: [1, 2, 4, 7]
Answer: [4, 3, 5, 8]
```

I've come up with the following algorithm. (There can be inaccuracies with indices, but I hope the main idea is clear).

1. Sort an array
2. Suppose we have an answer for ith element, i.e the segment L, which is before i, and segment R after i, such that |L|+|R|=k
3. Considering answer for i+1 element, we can take all elements from R (except a[i+1] itself), because they're even closer to a[i+1] if the array is sorted. Then I find other k-|R|+1 elements using two pointers, which move in different directions: l starting from i, r starting from i+|R|.

I don't like that I'm scanning previous elements using that l pointer. I suppose in a worst case scenario this algorithm would have O(n^2) time complexity. How can I improve it?

Comment: Is your exercise like [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-closest-elements-given-value/) where the array is presumed to be sorted, so definitionally the answer will always be some contiguous (ignoring the target itself) run of values that surrounds, or is adjacent to, the target?

Comment: Initially the array is unsorted.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to make sure "nearest" had the same meaning (referring solely to value, not to position).

Comment: Yes, it's referring to value.

Comment: Can you show an example of what an input and its corresponding output could look like?

Comment: For the record, I have no idea where your `Answer` comes from; you say you're finding the nearest integers, but each input should have two nearest integers, and your output is only producing a single value for each input, and not one that seems clearly related to the values that would appear in the window. Seems like `Answer:` should be something like `[[1,2], [0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2]]` (where the third element might be `[1, 3]` instead of `[0, 1]` depending on how you break ties) if you report the indices for the top and bottom of each window, or `[[2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 2], [2, 4]]`...

Comment: ... (third element might be `[2, 7]` with a different tie-breaking strategy) if you report the top and bottom values; I don't see how you'd convert either such means of describing the window to the since integers you're describing. It doesn't change my answer, it just leaves you to solve the mystery of how to convert from multiple values or indices per-element or indices to a single value.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that here I count the distance between nearest points.

Comment: Please clarify that in your question!

Comment: This needs a better explanation, how about showing a calculation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm could use a small tweak, that's it. It doesn't have `O(n²)` behavior. As is, it's by description `O(max(k × n, n log n))` because, if I'm reading you correctly, you *think* you're doing a `O(k)` scan outwards for each element that does not meaningfully benefit from the state of the window you used for the prior element. A small tweak would drop the `k × n` term to `n`, leaving it `O(cost-of-sorting algorithm)`, e.g. `O(n log n)` for good general purpose sorts, or some lower big-O greater than or equal to `O(n)` (for special purpose sorts like counting sort). And really, even without that tweak your existing code would already behave that way, you just don't see it (the tweak is more how you think about it, where the lack of the tweak just adds an additional `O(n)` step, and going from `n` to `2n` work doesn't change the big-O).

Your lower bound is `O(n log n)` if you use general purpose sorting. If the inputs fall in restricted ranges you could get `O(n + k)` computational work, with `O(k)` auxiliary storage, by using a special purpose sort like counting sort, where `k` is the size of the range, but we'll assume the integers can run from `-inf` to `inf`, so the `O(n + k)` is worse than `O(n log n)` general purpose sorting. Either way, that's a lower bound, if the rest of your algorithm is `O(n)` (and it has to be at least that high, since it must traverse the input element by element), then your sorting algorithm determines your overall work.

But while the way you describe it makes it *sound* like the per-element work for window adjustment is `O(k)`, in practice, it's actually doing `n - k` work to perform the window shifts for the whole *sequence*, with the `-k` factor spread over the whole sequence. Your auxiliary pointers would *never* scan backwards, because each time you move forward, your old value is closer to the new value than the furthest left value was by definition. So the only possibilities are:

1. The window for the prior value included the next value; replace the new value with the prior value, and then check:
   a. If some number of values above the old window are closer than the values at the bottom of the old window, the window slides forward (up to `k` times), or
   b. If the value above the old window is further than the bottom value in the window, the window doesn't shift (aside from the tweak to include the prior value in place of the next value)
2. The window for the prior value was entirely to its left: Replace the bottom of the window with the prior value unconditionally (instead of replacing the new value with the prior value as in #1, since the new value wasn't in there), then follow the same rules as case #1 (either the window remains unmoved beyond the swap, or it shifts right up to `k` times)

So the window sliding work can be as much as `k` at any given step (say, if `k` is 2 and you're at the value `8` in `[6, 7, 8, 100, 101, 102]`, then when you shift to `100`, your preliminary window from 6-7 unconditionally becomes 7-8, then you conditionally shift twice, first to 8-101, then to 101-102 where it stops). But since the only options at any given step are:

1. The window doesn't move (effectively moving backwards by one relative to advancing value's position), or
2. The window moves up to `k + 1` forward

this means that for every time the window moves forward a given number of steps, `s`, it must not have moved at all for `s` prior values (to move it backward enough that it *could* move forward that far), meaning that the peak per-element work is `O(k)`, but the amortized per-element work is `O(1)` (and it's actually slightly less than one, because over the course of the whole traversal, you move from a window that is definitionally `k` elements to the right of the current value, to one `k` elements to the left, and those leftward "moves" are actually staying put, so to speak, so your window shifts slightly *less* than once per element).

Your original plan is effectively the same, you'd just end up doing an unnecessary check at each stage to see if the window could move backwards (it never could). Since that single check is fixed cost, it's `O(1)` per-element, imposing no multiplier on the `O(n)` cost for processing the whole sequence.

**In short:** Your algorithm is already big-O optimal at `O(n)` for the work done post-sort. If you use a general purpose sorting algorithm, the `O(n log n)` work it does dominates everything else; a special purpose algorithm like counting sort would be the only way to lower your big-O of the whole process, including the sort, any lower, and the minimum cost would be `O(n)` even if you had a magical "sorts for free" tool.

Comment: Could you clarify one point, please. Doesn't "The window for the prior value was entirely to its right" mean that it includes the next value?

Comment: @JosephKirtman: That was a mistake; should have read "entirely to its left" (and therefore did *not* include the next value). I thought I'd caught all my stupid left/right screwups on rereading before posting, but of course I missed one. :-) Fixed.

Comment: Just for fun, I implemented this in C, and assuming I didn't make any mistakes, my solution didn't actually require a special case for "entirely to its left"; the window was tracked by a single pointer that pointed to the beginning of the window (when the window was entirely to the right of the current position, it pointed to the current position). The loop just checked if window start was at least `k + 1` from the end of the array and the difference between current val and `start[0]` was greater than that between current and `start[k + 1]`, incrementing start until that stopped being true.

Comment: The "special case" for "entirely to the left" was handled automatically there, because when it had been entirely to the left, and we advanced the current position, `start[k + 1]` was the same as the value at the new current position, and therefore any difference was "greater".